# How do I get a function to return different values depending on what is passed through the function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement, return

I'm having trouble getting my function to work properly. Depending upon the conditions, I want my function to return a new array by pushing into the new array. If the if conditions are false, I want to return two different string messages. Here is an example of my dataset:

```
let items = [
  { 
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits", 
    type: "book", 
    price: 18.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005", 
    type: "computer",
    price: 399.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Orangebook Pro", 
    type: "computer",
    price: 899.99
  }
```

So far, when my function takes in an array of items and a type of item as the string search word, it is returning an array of items that have a type that matches the type passed through the function. However, I also want my function to return two other things.

If there are no items in the cart array, return the string "Your cart does not have any items in it." Wouldn't this be written as `matches.length === 0`?
If there are no items that match the given type, return the string "No items found of that type. Please search for a different item.". Wouldn't this be written as `if (search != items[i].type)`?

How would I get these two strings to also return given the conditions? I feel as If I'm getting tripped up on the order in which these statements are being executed. Here is my code so far without the two string return values.

```
function findItems (items, search) {
  let matches = [];
  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].type.includes(search)) {
      matches.push(items[i])
    }
  }
  return matches;
}
```

In sum, I want the function to return an array if a search matches. If the first condition is false, I want to return one of two other string messages based on new conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a couple of conditionals to your function to return the appropriate strings dependent on the conditions you have described:

```js
let items = [{
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 18.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 399.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Orangebook Pro",
    type: "computer",
    price: 899.99
  }
];

function findItems(items, search) {
  if (items.length === 0) {
    return "Your cart does not have any items in it.";
  }
  let matches = [];
  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].type.includes(search)) {
      matches.push(items[i])
    }
  }
  if (matches.length === 0) {
    return "No items found of that type. Please search for a different item."
  }
  return matches;
}

console.log(findItems(items, 'computer'));
console.log(findItems(items, 'software'));
console.log(findItems([], 'computer'));
```

Note that if you take this approach, you will need to check the return value from the function to see if it is an array or a string and process the result differently.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I knew I had all the parts but I was writing them in the wrong order. Now I realize that checking to see if ```items.length === 0``` does not require running through the for loop. This data was already given to us and we can check this condition before we even loop through the array. This is why it needs to be first. Once we have our matches array, if there are no matches, then we can check if ```matches.length === 0``` but only after we have used the push method. Otherwise, this will always return as true because we intentionally set the array length to equal 0.

Comment: @ElinaMcGill indeed, you had all the parts. The explanation you have written in that comment describes perfectly how the code should and does work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning an array of items you can return a object. Then when you are using the return value of the function you can check the object properties to get the message or whatever you are hoping to get. Check the outputVal object in the following function.

```
function findItems (items, search) {
      let outputVal = { Message: "", 
                        matches: [] }
      
      for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].type.includes(search)) {
          outputVal.matches.push(items[i])
        }
      }
      if(outputVal.matches.length==0){
        outputVal.Message = "No Items Found!"
      }
      return outputVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
let items = [{itemName:"Effective Programming Habits",type:"book",price:18.99},{itemName:"Creation 3005",type:"computer",price:399.99},{itemName:"Orangebook Pro",type:"computer",price:899.99}];

const filterItems = (items, searchText) => {
  if(items.length === 0) {
    return "Your cart does not have any items in it.";
  } 
  const filteredItems = items.filter(item => item.type.includes(searchText));
  return filteredItems.length === 0 ? "No items found of that type. Please search for a different item.": filteredItems;
}

//One matching type from the list
console.log(filterItems(items, "book"));
//No matching types from the list
console.log(filterItems(items, "not found"));
//When the cart items are empty
console.log(filterItems([], "book"));
//Multiple matching types form the list
console.log(filterItems(items, "computer"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```